# Split by space or multiple spaces, a comma or comma followed by space

Tags: c#, regex

I did this regex

```
Regex.Split(sentence, @"\s+|,(?=\s)")
```

It works, but it also returns white spaces. Can you please help?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need this:

```
Regex.Split(sentence, @"(?:\s*,\s*)|\s+")
```

Comment: Actually the way you wrote it the first time works best @"\s*,\s*|\s+" the second one still gives me empty strings, I don't understand why

Comment: Ah ok got it, reverted back it

Comment: Why is it when I use @"(\s*,\s*)|\s" it also returns me commas in a separate string? I mean, it should either split by @"\s*,\s*" or by @"\s"

Comment: Actually without brackets is the right one as C# regex engine returns captured part also in resulting array. But `(?:)` will work fine see edited code.

Comment: Difference is capturing group vs non-capturing group.

Comment: Thank you. I know what they are, but I haven't used them for a while. I accepted your answer

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that the spaces your regex returns are spaces following a comma and single space. Try this:

```
Regex.Split(sentence, @"\s+|,(?=\s*)")
```